# How to download Data set from repository to WEKA

Tags: dataset, weka

How to download Data set from http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/datasets/Iris to WEKA?
and open it as arff
please help me

Answer (score 2):

First, download this http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data

Then, add the following on the top of this data-

```
@RELATION iris

@ATTRIBUTE sepallength  REAL
@ATTRIBUTE sepalwidth   REAL
@ATTRIBUTE petallength  REAL
@ATTRIBUTE petalwidth   REAL
@ATTRIBUTE class    {Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}

@DATA
```

You are good to go.

Comment: how can i convert it to .arff?

Comment: Just open a notepad, copy and paste the part I posted in the answer, then download the data and copy-paste it right after the part in my post on the notepad. Then just set the extension to ARFF.